# Is there a good source for finding common problems with ECLiPSe?

Tags: eclipse-clp

As a new ECLiPSe user I am running into problems.

I was able to consult a `.pl` file, but when I changed the extension to `.ecl` I got a file-does-not-exist message.

I was even able to run the `.pl` file, but couldn't access any of the subsidiary predicates. Only the longest one ran. (It was not called `main`.)

I finally added an `export` line, which solved the problem.

Loading `['../<current-directory>/file.ecl']` worked, but attempting to load `['file.ecl']` or `['./file.ecl']` produced a no-such-file message.

Is there a repository of newbie questions and answers or a mailing list of users?

Thanks.

Comment: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) says that questions asking us to recommend or find off-site resources are off-topic here.

Answer (score 1):

There is quite extensive documentation on [the ECLiPSe web site](https://eclipseclp.org), and also [mailing lists](https://eclipseclp.org/mailinglist.html) and the stackoverflow tag [eclipse-clp](/questions/tagged/eclipse-clp).

You should not have any problems with file extensions: .ecl and .pl are both accepted (with .ecl preferred if both are present), see [here](https://eclipseclp.org/doc/bips/kernel/compiler/compile-2.html).  There is the usual notion of the [current directory](https://eclipseclp.org/doc/bips/kernel/opsys/getcwd-1.html), which has to be taken into account when using relative pathnames.

You only need `export` directives when you use `module` directives -- for small experiments you can omit both.